# $p(z) = 2z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_0$ is a polynomial, need to show $|z|\le1$ and $|p(z)|>1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

> Let $p(z) = 2z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_0$ be a polynomial. Show that
>   there is a point $z$ such that $|z| \le 1$ and $|p(z)| > 1$.

I am new in complex-analysis and honestly I do not know where to start, I would really appreciate any hint or help.

Comment: What is $\int_C p(z)z^{-n-1}$ where $C$ is the unit circle?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Am new to complex analysis either. The value of this integral I think is $4\pi i$. But I don't understand how does it help solve the question asked by the OP. Can you give further hints please...

Comment: @shwetha What if $|p(z)|\le1$ on $C$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I got it! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown In general, can I say that this result is true for all complex polynomials with leading coefficient  > 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By contradiction, suppose $|p(z)|\leq 1$ for $|z|\leq1$. Then by Cauchy
$$2n!=|f^{(n)}(0)|=\left|\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(\zeta)d\zeta}{\zeta^{n+1}}\right|\leq n!,$$
contradiction.